# Tracking anonymous e-mail threat

Tags: email, spoofing, anonymous, attacks

A user spoofed/sent an email from http://emkei.cz/ with a very serious threat. Is it possible to trace this back or are we SOL?

There wasn't much in the email headers other than that it came from that site. We've checked DNS records for the site's IP - but the user was smart enough not to send it internally.

Comment: Tracing back to that email spoofing service won't get you much, they are setup that way on purpose.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately there's no practical way to trace an e-mail from a site like that.
For that reason many providers choose to block e-mail from those sites.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I was afraid of. It seems like to block receiving is turning a blind eye - but its not much different then being at ends with options.